# For Loop Issue JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[

```js
  // Define the variables
  var stringIn = [];
  var finalMessage = "Thanks for participating!";
  
  // Get input from user
  stringIn[0] = prompt("Enter the first string:");
  stringIn[1] = prompt("Enter the second string:");
  stringIn[2] = prompt("Enter the third string:");
  stringIn[3] = prompt("Enter the fourth string:");
  stringIn[4] = prompt("Enter the fifth string:");
  
  // For loop and display
  for(var myCounter = 0; myCounter < 5; myCounter++) {
    document.write("You entered: " + stringIn + "\n");
  }
  
  document.write("\n" + finalMessage);
```

My output should be:
You entered: Alpha
You entered: Bravo
You entered: Charlie
You entered: Delta
You entered: Echo

but I'm getting:

You entered: Alpha,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Echo
You entered: Alpha,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Echo
You entered: Alpha,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Echo
You entered: Alpha,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Echo
You entered: Alpha,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Echo

I've added my code to help with my problem. FireFox Web Console shows no errors and if I had an error, I wouldn't have any output. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: If you just write `+ stringIn +`, how's it supposed to know *which* element of `stringIn` to use? Hence, write `stringIn[myCounter]` to access the element at index `myCounter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to access the index of the stringIn in your iterator.

`stringIn[myCounter]`

```js
  // Define the variables
  var stringIn = [];
  var finalMessage = "Thanks for participating!";
  
  // Get input from user
  stringIn[0] = prompt("Enter the first string:");
  stringIn[1] = prompt("Enter the second string:");
  stringIn[2] = prompt("Enter the third string:");
  stringIn[3] = prompt("Enter the fourth string:");
  stringIn[4] = prompt("Enter the fifth string:");
  
  // For loop and display
  for(var myCounter = 0; myCounter < 5; myCounter++) {
    document.write("You entered: " + stringIn[myCounter] + "\n");
  }
  
  document.write("\n" + finalMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
  for(var myCounter = 0; myCounter < 5; myCounter++) {
    document.write("You entered: " + stringIn[myCounter] + "\n");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Less duplicates & array extras forEach

```js
const stringsNumber = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
let greetingText = 'Hello, and Welcome to my survey!\n\n';

stringsNumber.forEach(string => {
  const promptValue = prompt(`Enter the ${string} string:`);
  greetingText += `You entered: \"${promptValue}\" to be the ${string} string.\n`;
})

greetingText += '\nThanks for participating!';

document.write(greetingText);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```